# PHP: Compare arrays and copy first array value to second array value where second array value is null

Tags: php, arrays, null, copy

How to achieve the following ?

```
$array1 = array( id => '11', c1 => 'abcd', c2 => '4500', c3 => 'texas' ,c4=>'name' );
$array2 = array( id => '12', c1 => '',    c2 => '4500', c3 => 'arizona', c4=>'' );
```

I want to compare array 1 and array 2 and copy value from array 1 to array 2 when array 2 value is `null`. Example from above array i want to copy only c1 & c4 key from array 1 to array 2.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

How about a [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop:

```
foreach($array1 as $key=>$value){
    if(!$array2[$key]){
        $array2[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

And minimized, but a little less readable:

```
foreach($array1 as $key=>$value){
    $array2[$key] = $array2[$key] ? $array2[$key] : $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
foreach($array2 as $key=>$value)

if ($value==null) $array2[$key]=$array1[$key];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$array1 = array( id => '11', c1 => 'abcd', c2 => '4500', c3 => 'texas' ,c4=>'name' );
$array2 = array( id => '12', c1 => '',    c2 => '4500', c3 => 'arizona', c4=>'' );

foreach($array2 as $key =>$value)
{
  if($value == '')
 {
    $array2[$key] = $array1[$key];
 }  
 }  

print_r($array2);
 ?>
```